# Inheritance and deleting copy and move constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor, move-constructor

I want have a class with third-level inheritance. I will not move my classes or copy them. Actually, they will be created just once.  I want to test if it would be possible to delete the move and copy constructors and assignments as below:

```
MyClass ( MyClass && ) = delete;
MyClass ( const MyClass & ) = delete;
MyClass & MyClass :: operator= ( const MyClass & ) = delete;
MyClass & MyClass :: operator= ( MyClass && ) = delete;
```

When I did that I got an error in the base class constructor and base of base class:

```
initializing argument 1 of ‘Base::Base(const int&)’ [-fpermissive]
```

My constructor is like this:

```
Base(const string & name):BaseOfBase(name){

    };
```

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to delete all of move and copy constructors and assignment operators?
2. If it is possible, why I am getting error?
3. If it is possibe, is it a good choice?

Comment: By deleting a copy constructor you inhibit a compiler-generated move constructor, so `MyClass ( MyClass && ) = delete;` is redundant (ditto assignment operators)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having the error because apparently you are deleting your methods in the wrong place. Since you are prefixing them with the class name, looks like you are deleting them in the implementation. The right way to delete is in the class definition, like following:

```
class foo {
   foo(const foo& ) = delete;
};
```